# How to add executable file in resources folder in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

**Requirement**: To use an executable file within my resources folder

**Limitation**: I need to have that executable file within the resources folder, that is, I cannot have the executable file be present on the server from before

**Scenario**: When I am adding the executable file in the resources folder and then I am building the project using `mvn clean install`, then I have the following target folder structure.

target -> classes -> myExecutableFile

**Problem**: myExecutableFile present inside the target folder does not have executable permissions. Is there any way I can retain the executable permission for the file?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via Ant by doing something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <chmod file="target/script.sh" perm="755"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```